# Pandas Groupby having index that are not in the dataframe derived by subseting with Copy()

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

Problem: Find the ZIP's that are not repeated in df.ZIP (has to occur no more than once) and df.ST does not have values of '.'.
So I subset the original dataframe and applied Groupby - this still brought few rows that didn't meet the subset criteria(df.ST != '.'). So I created a separate df_us by subsetting with copy() option. Groupby still give the same index.

```
grouped = df[df.ST != '.'].groupby(['ZIP_CD'],sort=False) # grouping
df_size = pd.DataFrame({'ZIP':grouped.size().index, 'Count':grouped.size().values}) # Forming df around the group
df_count = df_size[df_size.Count==1] #df with Count=1
one_index = df_count.index.tolist() #gathering index
df_one = df.loc[one_index] #final df

df_us = df_data[df.ST != '.'].copy() # tried this too
```

The last code above still gives some index for values of '.' when I groupby. But df_us does not have any '.' at all. So this result in having same index column as above method - but for '.' values, rest of the row values are empty as df_us does not have them!

groupy is finding those index with '.' values no matter what I did.
Any solution?

update:
sample data =
index ST  ZIP_CD 
123   ca  94025
124   Toronto .
125   ga   30306
126   Italy  .
127   ca  94025

So correct answer is

```
    ST      ZIP_CD 
0   123     ca  94025
```

**Update:**
@Naveed's soln and mine below works fine. Do not know why the above code is flawed?

Comment: Please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with sample input, desired output and the current output, so that we can easily try and reproduce the problem.  Also see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391).

Comment: Updated post with sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with your original approach, using groupby:

```
grouped = df[df.ST != '.'].groupby(['ZIP_CD'],sort=False) # grouping
item = grouped.size()[grouped.size() < 2)].index # finding zip values
df_one = df[df.ZIP_CD.isin(item) #final df
```

I tested and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
# use lot where zip_cd ne .
# and zip_cd is not duplicated

# df.duplicated(subset='ZIP') : identifies the duplicates based on ZIP code and results in True/False series
# df.loc selects the rows from df, where duplicated is true
# df['ZIP'].isin : check if any of the DF is part of the zip filtered by df.loc
# using negation we eliminate them from being selected

# first condition is to check using loc that ZIP is not equal to "."

# combining these two together with logical AND, we filter DF where it holds true

# please note: while the same DF is used repeatedly, the filtered result is different for each of them.


(df.loc[df['ZIP'].ne('.') & 
~df['ZIP'].isin(df.loc[df.duplicated(subset='ZIP')]['ZIP'])]
 )
```

```
    index   ST  ZIP_CD
0   123     ca  94025
2   125     ga  30306
```

Comment: What does ~ do? Your code give the index for slicing?

Comment: you can use *!=* instead of *ne*. *~* is negation

Comment: Getting key error on ZIP_CD - just copied your code - you can see it here: https://trinket.io/python3/4e8795e263

Comment: in your sample data above, you had it as ZIP_CD. in the link you just shared it has ZIP. I just updated your code on trinket. check it out

Comment: Yes, I updated the data with <127   ca  94025>. Given 94025 occurs twice, it should only give "2   125     ga  30306". But the code also gives one of the duplicated value, which is ca.

Comment: share the trinket link

Comment: https://trinket.io/python3/2b63b6279f

Comment: not following you. it is only choosing CA once, as it is a duplicate. is that not what you wanted?

Comment: If a zip occurs twice or more. then it should not be selected at all. Only choose zip values that occurs once only - ie count of zip needs to be 1 only.

Comment: trinket is updated and so is the solution here. check it out

Comment: Yeah it works. Marked as the answer. I will check and see if it works on my original data. Thoughts on why my code is acting weird? df1 = df.copy() is to get an independent copy right - changes in df will not affect df1 once the copy is made?

Comment: that is correct. with copy() you get a separate copy of the data

Comment: Suppose, I have a new df that does not have the ".", called df2. Then, ~df2['ZIP'].isin(df2.loc[df2.duplicated(subset='ZIP')]['ZIP'])] works? Some explanation would help. Thanks

Comment: it will remove all rows that have a duplicate ZIP

Comment: your edits were incorrect. I updated your code in trinket. consider posting a separate question, if you have additional scenarios

Comment: What makes it to remove all duplicates Vs keep one of the duplicate?

Comment: You wanted to remove all duplicates and not keep any. See your comment above

Comment: Your code gives the right solution. Wondering how it does the desired results - originally it was keeping one of the duplicate?

Comment: added detailed description, hope it helps

Comment: Cool - awesome - that negation did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

@Naveed - thanks for helping me to learn. Your negation is something new to me. I also wrote an alternative soln using your negation.

```
df1 = df[df.ZIP != '.'] # eliminate invalid entries
v = df1.ZIP.value_counts() # counts values
df2 = df1[~df1.ZIP.isin(v.index[v.gt(1)])] # gets values more than once and negates
```

Link to try:
https://trinket.io/python3/b26eae2e0e

Worthy of mentioning @Jerrold110's approach which was modified:

```
items = v[v<2].index # items that appear less than twice
df2 = df1[df1['ZIP'].isin(items)
```

I do not know why the original groupby soln failed.